# SQL Grouping by first digit from sets of record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help in SQL
I have a set of records of Cost center ID below.
what I want to do is to segregate/group them by inserting column to distinguish the category.

as you can see all digits start in 7 is belong to the bold digits.
my expected out is on below image also.

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is there any criteria on what value must be set to specific ID

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen The official policy of Stack Overflow is to post question/answers/comments in English. I'd suggest you to post your comments in English henceforth, so that it is understandable to a wider section of Stack Overflow users.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Take some time and try to explain how to set those toFilter values. (And remember that rows are unordered.)

Comment: Please check my image.

Comment: as you can see on the image, if the first character is start on "7" it is belong to the coming different starting character, it means the next row with starting digit of "7" is belong to the next group

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny sorry for my previous comment. Maybe he actually wants to group the data according to the first digit of the number. As you can see to the image. And if the first digit of the number is not seven then It will group again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
(735121201),
(735120001),
(5442244),
(735141094),
(735141097),
(4008060),
(735117603),
(40100000),
(735142902),
(735151199),
(4010070)

;WITH TableWithRowId
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) RowId,
        ID
    FROM 
        @Tbl    
), TempTable
AS
(
    SELECT T.RowId + 1 AS RowId  FROM TableWithRowId T
    WHERE
        LEFT(T.ID, 1) != 7
), ResultTable
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.RowId ,
        T.ID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT TOP 1 A.RowId FROM TempTable A WHERE A.RowId > T.RowId ORDER BY A.RowId)) AS Flag
    FROM TableWithRowId T
)

SELECT * FROM ResultTable
```

Result:

```
RowId       ID          Flag
----------- ----------- ----------
1           735121201   1
2           735120001   1
3           5442244     1
4           735141094   2
5           735141097   2
6           4008060     2
7           735117603   3
8           40100000    3
9           735142902   4
10          735151199   4
11          4010070     4
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query is similer with  NEER's

```
;WITH test_table(CenterID)AS(
    SELECT '735121201' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735120001' UNION ALL
    SELECT '5442244' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735141094' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735141097' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4008060' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735117603' UNION ALL
    SELECT '40100000' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735142902' UNION ALL
    SELECT '735151199' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4010070'
),t1 AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS rn,CASE WHEN LEFT(t.CenterID,1)='7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isSeven
    FROM test_table AS t
),t2 AS(
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY t1.rn) AS toFilter
    FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t1 AS pt ON pt.rn=t1.rn-1 
    WHERE pt.CenterID IS NULL OR (t1.isSeven=1 AND pt.isSeven=0)
)
SELECT t1.CenterID,x.toFilter FROM t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 t2.toFilter FROM t2 WHERE t2.rn<=t1.rn ORDER BY rn desc) x
```

```
CenterID  toFilter
--------- --------------------
735121201 1
735120001 1
5442244   1
735141094 2
735141097 2
4008060   2
735117603 3
40100000  3
735142902 4
735151199 4
4010070   4
```